# In VBA Word, how to check if a paragraph contains any bold?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been teaching myself to use macros and VBA in work. I'm not code-minded so bear with me.

I need to be able to find paragraphs that are wholly bold (such as a subheading), but I've been struggling to figure it out or find any help online. I've seen similar questions but the responses are too complicated for me to really know what I'm replicating, despite trying to use parts that seem relevant.

My end goal is to, after finding a wholly bold paragraph, delete the character immediately following it (usually an empty line).

I did find something that suggested 0 being regular, -1 being entirely bold and 9999999 being partially bold, but I've been unable to get anything like that to work as I couldn't tell what code was relevant to me. I'd really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

The help that can be offered at this stage of your endeavour doesn't go beyond showing you how to help yourself.

The red line of your programming should be to find bold text in your document and determine if it is a whole paragraph. If it is then delete the blank line following it (and then continue searching for the next such paragraph?), and if it isn't, do nothing (and continue searching for the next bold text?).

At the heart of this plan is VBA's `Find` method. You can look it up on MSDN and/or you can do the search manually while recording your key strokes with the macro recorder. Either of these ways will be very confusing, perhaps the latter more than the former although it promises to be the shorter way to your target. Actually, much depends upon how you define your target. If you want to learn VBA the questions you meet will be challenges you can master. Others have done it before you.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the method that you were first considering. Create a Word file, and make sure that some text is bold and some is not. Highlight some plain text, or some bold text, or a range that includes plain and bold, and run the following routine.

```
Sub WhatTheHeck()
    If Selection.Font.Bold = True Then MsgBox "All is Bold"
    If Selection.Font.Bold = False Then MsgBox "None is Bold"
    If Selection.Font.Bold = wdUndefined Then MsgBox "Some is Bold" 
End Sub
```

When you get the hang of that, learn (or ask again) some of the many ways to select text programmatically (with the .Select method), and you'll have everything you need.
(For example, as somebody else suggested, you will be able to do a .Find with any complex criteria, combined with a .Select, and then call WhatTheHeck()).

NOTE: It is worth mentioning that many true/false properties in VBA can be true, false, or wdUndefined, and possibly other values. In general, wdUndefined means 'a combination of true and false'. I know that the Selection.Font.Hidden property can also be wdUndefined, meaning a combination of both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry I never responded sooner, I didn't get any notifications about answers (I expected that I would) and haven't been back on here since. I have code that searches for "^p" and replaces it with "^p^p" to create a blank space between each paragraph. From what you've shown, how could I run that "If Selection.Font.Bold = True Then..." for each paragraph in the entire document, so it does the search (and subsequent editing/formatting) for each paragraph?